# Python pyodbc sql server query process hangs when running. Shows as running for a long time in SQL sp_who2

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I am running some sql queries in Python (connecting to SQL azure).

example code :

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import pysftp

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                              'Server=<servername>;'
                              'Database=' + <databaseName>+ ';'
                              'UID=<user>;PWD=<pwd>;',timeout=180)

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[viewName] ORDER BY ST;"

df = pd.read_sql_query(sqlQuery, conn)
```

The view i am trying to run executes in seconds in SSMS. However in Python, seems to just run and hang. I am trying to read into a Pandas dataframe.

This code was working 2 days ago and now has started failing.

I would appreciate some advice as I am very stuck now!

Comment: At a guess, the table is not indexed properly. Please show the table and indeex definitions, and please share the query plan for your query via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: well, it runs in seconds in ssms?
Why would it not do the same in python?
Or does python intepert it differently?

Comment: Anything is possible (especially give it's actually a view), for example there may be two different indexes and one works better than the other. Slight differences in settings in Pyodbc may cause different compilation and use the wrong index. Without further info, cannot help.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkGIw2LQ2

Comment: Hmmm, given the size of that query, it's not surprising you are having issues, but it's a too big to give a definitive answer. Seeing as there are quite a number of sorts and hashes, the indexes probably need some work, and you could probably do with a good dose of window functions also.

Comment: im open to suggestions.

Comment: depends on what are you gonna do with the results?

Comment: the results are to be exported to csv, then uploaded to an sftp site

Comment: well, there's your problem, you can use bcp for that task, putting it into pandas is like digging up the earth and put it nicely in small plastic bottles just do take them to the dump

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not _"run in seconds in SSMS"_, but merely _returns first rows_ in seconds to SSMS.

Comment: @mustaccio it does run in seconds.
3 to be precise.

Comment: not used bcp before. something new to learn then.
any examples you can share?

Comment: it could be that ssms runs with different SET settings, which python doesn't have, and python version triggers some statistics recompilation, while ssms doesn't. since your query is pretty large, the stats recompile can take minutes itself

Comment: you can read some here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/ but there's probably a lot of code here on stackoverflow on how to call bcp from python. The biggest issue is usually how to add colum nheaders which bcp doesn't do automatically, but it's also solvable. and usually bcp is darn fast

Comment: i can run bcp from cmd prompt, but yes, each column gives me a prompt.
Need to figure out how to automate this..

Comment: Have a read through the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) documentation. You can avoid the prompts for column information if you [create a format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#h-create-format-files), you then include a reference to that format file when you export data.